# No handlers could be found for logger "kazoo.client"

Tags: python, logging, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

While giving the hardcoded value for the following code , its working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
import os

nodes = ["172.22.105.53"]

zk = KazooClient(hosts='172.22.105.53:2181')

output : no error
```

But the following lines gives error like **No handlers could be found for logger "kazoo.client"**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
import os

nodes = ["172.22.105.53"]

lead = "172.22.105.53"
zk = KazooClient(hosts='lead:2181')
```

any help on this regard is quietly appreciable.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please give further details of the problem, what is your set up, what are you trying to achieve? expected outcome etc. What are you working on? The the more (useful) detail the more likely you will get an answer

Comment: lead is string so it should be concatenated. So zk = KazooClient(hosts=lead+':2181')